# tessellation geometry nodes: how do i set border?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

[image]
How do I get the generation to be made like the one in the square? and not the way it is out?

Comment: i am not sure if i understood your question right, but if you already have this hexgonal pattern with GN, you just have to add another circle with 6 vertices and some extrusion to your instance - thats it. Or did i miss something? if you provide your blend file, i will extend it and show how you can do it

Comment: or do you just want a square result? -> then just use a boolean modifier with a cube

Comment: instead of generating with the "normal" border as the white part shows, I wanted it to generate with the same border as the selected part (blue)

Comment: but the white part has no border...!?

Comment: I added an image of the current generation and the generation I'm looking for

Comment: did you try using the mesh boolean node?

Comment: yes, and almost that

Answer (score 3):

Just use a boolean node like this:

[image]

[image]